# Changing the style of a component that has its classList dynamically changed, using styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to toggle a component's classList, and conditionally change its style based on that.

I'm doing the following:

```
const CalendarEvents = styled.div``;
const Days = styled.div``;

const Calendar = styled.div`
  ~ .show {
    ${CalendarEvents} {
      ${Days} {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I have a button that toggles the class `'show'`, but the component doesn't seem to change. When the button is clicked, then the `Days` component should have the `display: none` style.

Am I incorrectly using the `~` selector?

[image: cranky-silence-53kx8]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use The ampersand `(&)` instead of `~` combinator selector which needed to refer back to the main component `Calendar` when it has `.show` class first then you can do nesting styles.

```
const Calendar = styled.div`
 &.show {
    ${CalendarEvents} {
      ${Days} {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
`;

// equal to .Calendar.show > CalendarEvents > Days { ... }
```

See Docs: [Pseudoelements, pseudoselectors, and nesting](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting)